# Merge XML documents

Tags: xml

I need to "merge" two XML documents, overwriting the overlapsed attributes and elements. For instance if I have **document1**:

```
<mapping>
    <key value="assigned">
        <a/>
    </key>
    <whatever attribute="x">
        <k/>
        <j/>
    </whatever>
</mapping>
```

and **document2**:

```
<mapping>
    <key value="identity">
        <a/>
        <b/>
    </key>
</mapping>
```

I want to merge the two like this:

```
<mapping>
    <key value="identity">
        <a/>
        <b/>
    </key>
    <whatever attribute="x">
        <k/>
        <j/>
    </whatever>
</mapping>
```

I prefer **Java** or **XSLT**-based solutions, **ant** will do fine, but if there's an easy way to do that in **Rake**, **Ruby** or **Python** please don't be shy :-)

**EDIT:** actually I find I'd rather use an automated tool/script, even [writing it by myself](http://web.archive.org/web/20100818203850/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes), because manually merging some 30 XML files is a bit unwieldy... :-(

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the rules you want to apply? Will there always only be one element with the same name? Do you go deeper into the tree to compare child elements when both documents have the same element (with identical attributes)?

Comment: By the way, your example is not well-formed ("whatever" is not closed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you like XSLT, there's a nice merge script I've used before at:
[Oliver's XSLT page](http://web.archive.org/web/20160809092524/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @stm - I've replaced it with the archive.org link to that page

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com) can do this for you.  It can merge two XML files together, and can be run from the command line, so you can batch everything up together, run it and just resolve any conflicts (such as the changing attribute value of 'key' in your above example) manually with a few clicks.  (You can tell it to run silently providing there are no conflicts.)

It can perform two-way and three-way comparisons of XML files and two-way and three-way merges.  (Where a three-way operation assumes the two files being compared/merged have a common ancestor.)

Comment: According to their webpage _Project: Merge is the predecessor to Oso XML Merge, and can therefore be considered as a discontinued product at this time._

Comment: Oso XML Merge has improved functionality over Project: Merge.  More information is available at the Oso Corporation website here:  https://osocorporation.com/xmlmerge/index.php  (Disclaimer: Oso Corporation is my company, Project: Merge/Oso XML Merge are my products.) :)

Answer (score 4):

Check [XmlCombiner](https://github.com/atteo/xml-combiner) which is a Java library that implements XML merging in exactly this way. It is loosely based on a similar functionality offered by [plexus-utils](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/Xpp3DomUtils.java) library.

XmlCombiner default convention is to overwrite the overlapping attributes and elements. But the exact merging behavior can be altered using special ['combine.self' and 'combine.children'](https://github.com/atteo/xml-combiner#controlling-the-merging-behavior) attributes.

Usage:

```
import org.atteo.xmlcombiner.XmlCombiner;

// create combiner
XmlCombiner combiner = new XmlCombiner();
// combine files
combiner.combine(firstFile);
combiner.combine(secondFile);
// store the result
combiner.buildDocument(resultFile);
```

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 2):

(also using [Oliver's XSLT stlyesheets](http://web.archive.org/web/20160809092524/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/))

XSLT merge from PowerShell:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][string]$file1,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][string]$file2,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $True)][string]$path
)

# using only abs paths .. just to be safe
$file1 = Join-Path $(Get-Location) $file1
$file2 = Join-Path $(Get-Location) $file2
$path = Join-Path $(Get-Location) $path

# awesome xsl stylesheet from Oliver Becker
# http://web.archive.org/web/20160502194427/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt
$xsltfile = Join-Path $(Get-Location) "merge.xslt"

$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings
$XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1

$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load($xsltfile , $XsltSettings, $(New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver))

[System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList]$al = [System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList]::new()
$al.AddParam("with", "", $file2)
$al.AddParam("replace", "", "true")

[System.Xml.XmlWriter]$xmlwriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($path)
$xslt.Transform($file1, $al, $xmlwriter)
```

Using 'plain ol' Saxon:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar .\FileA.xml .\merge.xslt with=FileB.xml replace=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure as to whether you want to do this programatically or not.

Edit: Ah, I posted that before the Edit. Don't I look like an idiot now!  ;)

If you just want to merge two files together, IBM have an [XML Diff and Merge Tool](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/xmldiffmerge), and there's also Altova's [DiffDog](http://www.altova.com/products/diffdog/diff_merge_tool.html).

Comment: Never mind, I've been a bit clumsy and posted the question before the text was complete... who does look like an idiot, now? ;-)
As for your answer: thanks a lot, I'm investigating into the tools you suggested and I will let you know if they saved my... bacon :-)

Comment: the link to IBM's XML Diff and Merge Tool no longer works