# GIT merge, diff XML Formatting, Automation

Tags: xml, git, xslt, xpath, automation

What i would like to achive:
Basically i want to make something like an automated XML formater (XSLT might be good) which involves GIT for Merging and resolving Merging Conflicts automatically.
Technology (Java,Git,XML,Xpath,XSLT)

Situation:
I have already made some research (Clearly i don't know enough) on topic (Three-way merge, Git Pro book, Some StackOverflow topic, XSLT, weeschool) but the tools i found there and the solutions not solving my questions, i feel lost right now and don't really know what should i look into it or how to proceed with my problem, what articles you would suggest? Anything which could help me to solve my problem/build up a theory/direct me to the correct dirrection, i appreciate.

Unfortunately i also have a deadline and i want to be more efficient then just blindly reading some stuff from internet.

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be more specific, add a short understandable sample of your expected input and output. Your question is too broad.

Comment: There are 10 Configuration XML, i want to modify something in the Configuration which affects some of the 10 Configuration XML (Lats say it affect 5 of them), then someone else do some different Configuration modification. The 2nd change affects lets say 3 of the Configuration XML. I want to be able to merge, and format this modification (XML) as Automatically as possible. Does this help to understand my problem?

Comment: yes, a bit. You should add concrete samples, don't need to be real but must represent with code what you are trying to do.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/80609/1256452

Comment: Thanks for the usefull answers, right now i know what to do next,meanwhile searching for  cdt.xml Ordering and formatting topics, if you know some good stuff please let me know :) i want to build it together with git