# How to join several XML files using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several XML files with a similar structure. Need to join these files into one using XSLT with grouping as shown below.

01.xml  (Report number 1, two groups - "Local" and "Web")

```
<Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>22</A-1>
                 <A-2>33</A-2>
                 <A-3>44</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>55</A-1>
                 <A-2>66</A-2>
                 <A-3>77</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>
```

02.xml  (Report number 2, two groups - "Local" and "Web"))

```
<Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>33</B-1>
                 <B-2>44</B-2>
                 <B-3>55</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>66</B-1>
                 <B-2>77</B-2>
                 <B-3>88</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>
```

03.xml  (Report number 3, two groups - "Local" and "Web")

```
<Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>44</C-1>
                 <C-2>55</C-2>
                 <C-3>66</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>77</C-1>
                 <C-2>88</C-2>
                 <C-3>99</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>
```

Expected result with grouping :

```
<Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>22</A-1>
                 <A-2>33</A-2>
                 <A-3>44</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>33</B-1>
                 <B-2>44</B-2>
                 <B-3>55</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>44</C-1>
                 <C-2>55</C-2>
                 <C-3>66</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>55</A-1>
                 <A-2>66</A-2>
                 <A-3>77</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>66</B-1>
                 <B-2>77</B-2>
                 <B-3>88</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>77</C-1>
                 <C-2>88</C-2>
                 <C-3>99</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use? It seems just like a grouping problem or perhaps, if you use XSLT 3, like a use case of `xsl:merge`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge XML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80609/merge-xml-documents)

Comment: Martin, I use Saxon XSLT processor, XSLT version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can specify what is the exact problem? Is it about reading the documents? Use [document()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_document.html) for this.

I would:
 - store all the descendants of the  elements in `$group_{name}`
 - group the items inside the variables
 - create a structure for the new document
 - use `<xsl:copy-of>` or `<xsl:sequence>` to output the values of the variables where they belongs to

For instance,

Store the element ReportN1 in the variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="xml_01_local-r1" select="document('01.xml')//group[@name='local']/ReportN1"/>
```

Later output it like this

```
<Group name="Local">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$xml_01_local-r1"/>
</Group>
```

There should be certainly more efficient ways to do it, but this one will work.

Comment: OS-50101, I have no big expirience at XSL transforming, could you show me some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have exactly three documents you can load them as three separate parameters using the `doc` function (e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc1" select="doc('01.xml')"/>`) and then it is simply a question of nested grouping, here is an XSLT 3 (is supported by Saxon 9.8 and later) example as I have made used for one grouping of a composite grouping key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc1"><Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>22</A-1>
                 <A-2>33</A-2>
                 <A-3>44</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN1>
              <Data Kods="10011">
                 <A-1>55</A-1>
                 <A-2>66</A-2>
                 <A-3>77</A-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN1>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>
</xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="doc2"><Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>33</B-1>
                 <B-2>44</B-2>
                 <B-3>55</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN2>
              <Data Kods="10022">
                 <B-1>66</B-1>
                 <B-2>77</B-2>
                 <B-3>88</B-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN2>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports></xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="doc3">
<Reports>
   <Year Year="2019">
      <Month mon1="1" mon2="12">
         <Group name="Local">
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>44</C-1>
                 <C-2>55</C-2>
                 <C-3>66</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
         <Group name="Web">
            <ReportN3>
              <Data Kods="10033">
                 <C-1>77</C-1>
                 <C-2>88</C-2>
                 <C-3>99</C-3>
              </Data>
            </ReportN3>
         </Group>
      </Month>
   </Year>
</Reports>      
  </xsl:param>


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <Report>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$doc1/*/Year, $doc2/*/Year, $doc3/*/Year" group-by="@Year">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Month" composite="yes" group-by="@mon1, @mon2">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Group" group-by="@name">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="@*, current-group()!*"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Report>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LUU

There I have inlined the sample XML data but of course you can as well load them with the `doc` function or in general use the `collection` function with Saxon 9 e.g. `<xsl:param name="docs" select="collection('?select=*.xml')"/>` to load several documents. You would then replace the `<xsl:for-each-group select="$doc1/*/Year, $doc2/*/Year, $doc3/*/Year" group-by="@Year">` with `<xsl:for-each-group select="$docs!*!Year" group-by="@Year">`.

For XSLT 2 you would use no `composite` attribute on the second grouping but then `group-by="concat(@mon1, '|', @mon2)"` and the `!` is also not available so if the order matters then use `select="for $doc in $docs return $doc/*/Year"` instead of `select="$docs!*!Year"`.

I assume the stylesheet is used with a dummy input document or with `-it` as the command line option for Saxon 9.8 and later, that would be another change you need if you use an older version, I think XSLT 2 doesn't allow `<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">` so you would need to use a different name like `<xsl:template match="/" name="main">` and start Saxon with `-it:main`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Martin. It's works !