# How to merge two similar XML files using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files with a similar structure. Need to merge these xml files into one using XSLT.

01.xml (with two references REF01 and REF10)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<common-indicators>
    <common-indicator>
        <reference>REF01</reference>
        <name>name1</name>
        <reports>
            <report>
                <id>15</id>
                <name>name15</name>
            </report>
            <report>
                <id>16</id>
                <name>name16</name>
            </report>
        </reports>
    </common-indicator>
    <common-indicator>
        <reference>REF10</reference>
        <name>name10</name>
        <reports>
            <report>
                <id>30</id>
                <name>name30</name>
            </report>
            <report>
                <id>32</id>
                <name>name32</name>
            </report>
            <report>
                <id>34</id>
                <name>name34</name>
            </report>
        </reports>
    </common-indicator>
</common-indicators>
```

XSLT transformation (include xml file to merge as param1 with two references REF02 and REF10) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:param name="param1">
    <common-indicators>
        <common-indicator>
            <reference>REF02</reference>
            <name>name2</name>
            <reports>
                <report>
                    <id>17</id>
                    <name>name17</name>
                </report>
                <report>
                    <id>18</id>
                    <name>name18</name>
                </report>
            </reports>
        </common-indicator>
        <common-indicator>
            <reference>REF10</reference>
            <name>name10</name>
            <reports>
                <report>
                    <id>36</id>
                    <name>name36</name>
                </report>
                <report>
                    <id>38</id>
                    <name>name38</name>
                </report>
                <report>
                    <id>40</id>
                    <name>name40</name>
                </report>
            </reports>
        </common-indicator>
    </common-indicators>
 </xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$param1/common-indicators/common-indicator" /> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="common-indicators">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="common-indicator" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItems" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected xml result (REF01, REF02 and merged REF10 ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<common-indicators>
   <common-indicator>
      <reference>REF01</reference>
      <name>name1</name>
      <reports>
         <report>
            <id>15</id>
            <name>name15</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>16</id>
            <name>name16</name>
         </report>
      </reports>
   </common-indicator>
   <common-indicator>
      <reference>REF02</reference>
      <name>name2</name>
      <reports>
         <report>
            <id>17</id>
            <name>name17</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>18</id>
            <name>name18</name>
         </report>
      </reports>
   </common-indicator>
   <common-indicator>
      <reference>REF10</reference>
      <name>name10</name>
      <reports>
         <report>
            <id>30</id>
            <name>name30</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>32</id>
            <name>name32</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>34</id>
            <name>name34</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>36</id>
            <name>name36</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>38</id>
            <name>name38</name>
         </report>
         <report>
            <id>40</id>
            <name>name40</name>
         </report>
      </reports>
   </common-indicator>
</common-indicators>
```

Comment: Its not the same xml structure as there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890184/how-to-join-several-xml-files-using-xslt     please help

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: using Saxon-HE-10.5.jar processor.

Comment: You need edit your question, and add Saxon-HE-10.5 there.

Comment: Also add the rules for merging and the expected result after merging.

Comment: Edit your question and show any wanted results there in a well formatted way.

Comment: something is wrong with the stackoverflow - does not allow to save  formatted xml.
I put expected result as minified xml

Comment: or you can check here doc file with full description of the problem 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B7oF8EGjTmos5P_GWzzUKjA4v9KA8GqO/edit

Comment: A single example does not really suffice to tell us the rules for merging; what is supposed to happen if both input sources have e.g. a `report` with `id` as e.g. `30` for `common-indicator` with `reference` `REF10`? What do you want to have in the result if the input source have duplicates in terms of `id` for a specific `reference`?

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 3.0 introduced *merge* functionality.

Here is a conceptual example for you.

**List1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
   <item id="1">
      <descr ref="a"/>
      <descr ref="b"/>
   </item>
   <item id="2">
      <descr ref="c"/>
      <descr ref="d"/>
   </item>
   <item id="3">
      <descr ref="e">one</descr>
      <descr ref="f">one</descr>
   </item>
</list>
```

**List2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
   <item id="4">
      <descr ref="z"/>
      <descr ref="y"/>
   </item>
</list>
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <!--fully qualified path's spaces shall be encoded via encode-for-uri()-->
    <!--directory and file names are case sensitive-->
    <xsl:param name="directory" select="'c:/XSLT30/Merging two XML files_XSLT30'"/>
    <xsl:param name="wildcard" select="'List*.xml'"/>
    
    <!--<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>-->
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <list>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="collection('file:///' || encode-for-uri($directory) || '?strip-space=yes;select=' || $wildcard)"
                    select="list/item">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="@id"
                        order="ascending"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:sequence select="current-merge-group()"/>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </list>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
   <item id="1">
      <descr ref="a"/>
      <descr ref="b"/>
   </item>
   <item id="2">
      <descr ref="c"/>
      <descr ref="d"/>
   </item>
   <item id="3">
      <descr ref="e">one</descr>
      <descr ref="f">one</descr>
   </item>
   <item id="4">
      <descr ref="z"/>
      <descr ref="y"/>
   </item>
</list>
```